# is it Possible to install apk file from personal website without market like googleplay?

Tags: installation, android-install-apk

I'm making a website that offers apk file. Is it possible to install the apk directly to phone from my website when clicking the install button without market like google play?
I already try to make this but once i clicked install button, it only download the file and place to filemanager and did not install. Is it possible? if yes, how can i do that with php? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can Install any android application in your phone, it can be from any e-mail,
website or any other medium it doesn't matter. 

To Install the outside app you must change the settings first.

1. Swipe down from the top of the screen and tap the Settings button.

   Tap the Security button beneath the Personal subheading.

   Scroll down to the Device Administration subheading, tap Unknown Sources, and OK in the following warning pop-up.

Sorry I cant tell you about PHP

Comment: I know that thing about installing apk thru device admin, but i wanted to know if theres possible to make script in php that will install the apk directly to phone like in google play. if you download the app, it directly install in your phone. Thanks to reply :)